# Incremental back from one network location to another network location via ROBOCOPY?

Tags: backup, robocopy

Here is the scenario,

```
SOURCE - //END-PC/Sourcefolder

DEST   - //FIRST-PC/Destinationfolder
```

Source folder has around 60-70GB of data which are Excel, Word, jpeg, pdf and all sort of work related documents.

Here I need to do incremental backup in a daily basis without any modification done to the source? Office works 24x7 so I need to backup data in a daily basis.

Please suggest best option or kindly post them as command here itself

`/z` `/np` `/xo` `/e`  are not options, which I tried. It found that the source has not changed which is good

Comment: What have you actually tried? Robocopy has many parameters. Which didn't do what you wanted?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Admitting you `Haven't tried anything yet` isn't going to go well with this community. We're not here to do your work. We expect people to have done some research and made at least *some* effort, where you've clearly done neither! Robocopy is well documented. I have voted to close. However, you can edit your question and add what you've tried, explain where you're stuck and we can help :) -1

Comment: /z /np /xo /e these are the option which I tried, my priority is not to make any changes accidentally or by purpose to the source files.

Comment: Post the code you intend to use (again, please edit the question). I'll then remove my -1 and my close vote!

Comment: Also, test it on a different folder first :)

Comment: Alright thank you I've test it with few test files and folder and it seems to be working and my question is will this ever make any sort of changes to the source ? my options used are " /z /np /xo /e "

Comment: You need to edit your question and ask that

Answer (score 0):

You changed your question in the comments . You wrote

Alright thank you I've test it with few test files and folder and it seems to be working and my question is will this ever make any sort of changes to the source ? my options used are " /z /np /xo /e " –

The answer is no. As long as the version of robocopy isn't changed and you don't change syntax it will do exactly what it does.

IMO it is totally safe and will not delete/remove source files.

Depending on the tags I think it's possible that the source attributes may be affected (now or in the future)   but not the actual content.